# Esper Sliding window details of an event

Tags: esper

For an event which satisfies a rule, how to get the related Sliding Window(ID/name) details in the listener.

e.g, we have the rule -

```
select * from StockTick.win:time(10) having avg(price) > 20
```

We receive StockTick events A, B (as part of sliding window 1).

Events B,C as part of sliding window 2 (as part of sliding window 2).

Event A is part of sliding window 1, Event B is part of both windows 1 and 2, Event C is part of sliding window 2.

Now, for each event A, B and C(B being received twice in the listener), how do I find in the listener which sliding window(1 or 2) the event beans A, B and C are associated with.

I have used the UpdateListener and StatementAwareUpdateListener. I am not able to get information about sliding windows related to the event bean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking but if you just have 2 different queries like so

Window 1)

```
select * from StockTick.win:time(10) having avg(price) > 20
```

and window 2)

```
select * from StockTick.win:time(10) having avg(price) > 40
```

Then what I do is use 2 different event handlers to differentiate which window each event came from like so:

```
EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.GetDefaultProvider();
EPAdministrator admin = epService.EPAdministrator;

EPStatement avg20 = admin.CreateEPL("select * from StockTick.win:time(10) having avg(price) > 20");
EPStatement avg40 = admin.CreateEPL("select * from StockTick.win:time(10) having avg(price) > 40");
avg20.Events += HandleAvg20Event;

  // Example event handler code
  public void HandleAvg20Event(Object sender, UpdateEventArgs e) {
      Console.WriteLine("event came from avg20 stream");
  }

avg40.Events += HandleAvg40Event;

// Example event handler code
public void HandleAvg40Event(Object sender, UpdateEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("event came from avg40 stream");
 }
```

Comment: My question may not be clear. I shall try to explain it. When a sliding window (e.g. win:time(30 sec)) starts, we have as series of windows(overlapping) each of span 30 sec running. Does Esper provide any window listener that is triggered at the start and close of each sliding window ?

Answer (score 0):

you should have 3 seperate statements for event A , B & C

and attach seperate listeners to them .

For example I have stock events coming for securites - SAPE , PNG and GOOG . I will write 3 seperate queries like

```
@Name('Select SAPE > 20')
select * from StockTick.win:time(10) having avg(price) > 20 and symbol = 'SAPE'

@Name('Select PNG > 25')
select * from StockTick.win:time(10) having avg(price) > 25 and symbol = 'PNG'

@Name('Select GOOG> 19')
select * from StockTick.win:time(10) having avg(price) > 19 and symbol = 'GOOG'
```

In code I'll get the statements as follows

```
EPStatement PNGSignal  = epService.getEPAdministrator().getStatement(
                "Select PNG > 25");


EPStatement SAPESignal  = epService.getEPAdministrator().getStatement(
                "Select SAPE > 20");

EPStatement GOOGSignal  = epService.getEPAdministrator().getStatement(
                "Select GOOG > 19");
```

Then for each statement I'll attach an update Listener to each statement

```
PNGSignal.addListener( new updateListener {@Override
        public void update(EventBean[] arg0, EventBean[] arg1) {
                          //Sysout - inside PNG Signal 

            }
                     });

GOOGSignal.addListener( new updateListener {@Override
        public void update(EventBean[] arg0, EventBean[] arg1) {
                          //Sysout - inside GOOG Signal 

            }
                     });
```

for more information you can refer to my CEP/ESPER Video 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=emwwpvfaddw

Comment: My question may not be clear. I shall try to explain it. When a sliding window (e.g. win:time(30 sec)) starts, we have as series of windows(overlapping) each of span 30 sec running. Does Esper provide any window listener that is triggered at the start and close of each sliding window ?

Comment: @tradetronics, how is your solution you posted different from mine posted a day earlier?